# dateSignedTabs does not work

Tags: docusignapi

I cannot get a date tab to appear on the PDF.  Here is my envelope.  I can get the sign here tab working fine.  The date tabs do not work.  There does not seem to be any good help on the date tabs.  Any clues..?

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
  <status>sent</status>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <name>TEST0467960B.pdf</name>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <recipients>
    <signers>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <email>xxxx@xxx.com</email>
        <name>First EMailer</name>
        <tabs>
          <dateSignedTabs>
           <dateSigned>
              <xPosition>225</xPosition>
              <yPosition>655</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>5</pageNumber>
              <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
              <name>Date Signed</name>
              <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            </dateSigned>
          </dateSignedTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <email>xxx@xxx.com</email>
        <name>Second signed</name>
        <tabs>
          <dateSignedTabs>
            <dateSigned>
              <xPosition>225</xPosition>
              <yPosition>655</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>5</pageNumber>
              <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
              <name>Date Signed</name>
              <recipientId>2</recipientId>
            </dateSigned>
          </dateSignedTabs>
        </tabs>
     </signer>
    </signers>
  </recipients>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing it correctly.

[DocuSign REST API Help](https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help) has some pretty good examples of XML formatting most of the calls. JSON appears to be there for everything, XML is there for most things.

Your call works just fine for me with moving them to page 1 on a sample document that has 1 page

Here's my request to create a quick draft to check. And both recipients have a Date Signed tab on page 1 near the bottom, they are however stacked on top of each other.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
  <status>created</status>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <name>TEST0467960B.pdf</name>
      <documentBase64>{omitted}</documentBase64>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <recipients>
    <signers>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <email>xxxx@xxx.com</email>
        <name>First EMailer</name>
        <tabs>
          <dateSignedTabs>
           <dateSigned>
              <xPosition>225</xPosition>
              <yPosition>655</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
              <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
              <name>Date Signed</name>
              <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            </dateSigned>
          </dateSignedTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <email>xxx@xxx.com</email>
        <name>Second signed</name>
        <tabs>
          <dateSignedTabs>
            <dateSigned>
              <xPosition>225</xPosition>
              <yPosition>655</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
              <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
              <name>Date Signed</name>
              <recipientId>2</recipientId>
            </dateSigned>
          </dateSignedTabs>
        </tabs>
     </signer>
    </signers>
  </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```