# DocuSign API not asking or setting the dateSigned though it is present in the xml

Tags: date, docusignapi

Having followed the example found earlier here on StackOverflow ([dateSignedTabs does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111561/datesignedtabs-does-not-work)), I still fail to get a signature date to appear.  Here's a snippet of the xml.

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
       <emailSubject>Boiler Contract -00006)</emailSubject>
       <status>sent</status>
       <documents>
          <document>
             <documentId>1</documentId>
             <name>VDBK SW6-CSIK-0001.pdf</name>
          </document>
       </documents>
       <recipients>
          <signers>
             <signer>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
                <note>Team</note>
                <email>joebloggs@gmail.com</email>
                <name>Eric Test6-1</name>
                <tabs>
                   <signHereTabs>
                      <signHere>
                         <xPosition>58</xPosition>
                         <yPosition>617</yPosition>
                         <documentId>1</documentId>
                         <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                      </signHere>
                   </signHereTabs>
                   <dateSignedTabs>
                      <dateSigned>
                         <xPosition>58</xPosition>
                         <yPosition>440</yPosition>
                         <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
                         <name>Date Signed</name>
                         <documentId>1</documentId>
                         <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                         <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                      </dateSigned>
                   </dateSignedTabs>
                </tabs>
             </signer>
          </signers>
       </recipients>
    </envelopeDefinition>
```

Can anybody spot why this is off?

Comment: Hi - I just used your request XML in Postman and actually do see both a DateSigned tab and a SignHere tab.  If you create a draft envelope (status=created) then you can log into DocuSign afterwards and open it in the sending/tagger screen.  You should see all tabs there.  Also keep in mind that DateSigned is rendered as flattened text so it may be occluding your document text (so just hard to see).

Comment: I just sent you an envelope using your xml but my own doc to 30111561@mailinator.com - would you open that up (go here: https://www.mailinator.com/inbox2.jsp?public_to=30111561) and see if it's what you are trying to get?

Comment: This is now working.  I'm unsure as to why the date did not appear and now does appear.